# Where should I put the following method?

Tags: java, sql, dao, api-design

I have 2 tables with the relationship:

```
Purchase 1:m Payment
```

- Each purchase has a primary key "purchaseId".
- Each payment has a primary key "transactionId" and a foreign key "purchaseId";

I have a DAO class for each table. Now I want to implement a function

```
List<Payment> findPaymentsByPurchaseId(int purchaseId)
```

To make the API feels more intuitive, should I put this function in

1. PurchaseDAO to indicate "if I want to find anything based on Purchase information, I just call a function in PurchaseDAO"
2. PaymentDAO to indicate "if I want to find Payment information, I just call a function in PaymentDAO"

Which one do you feel more intuitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could go multiple places.

In a purchase DAO, you'd want:

```
List<Payment> getPaymentsFor(Purchase) // or find..., or findByPurchase, or...
```

In a payment DAO, you'd want:

```
Purchase getPurchaseFor(Payment)
```

(Whether it's an ID or the object is more philosophical than technical; use whatever works for you. Exposing an ID might be considered a leaky abstraction, although it's more a cognitive one, since having a PK doesn't mean it *must* be a DB PK, it could just be a GUID.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd put it in `PaymentDAO` as it's returning payments but I'd also make it more generic

```
List<Payment> findByPurchase(Purchase purchase)
```

Comment: I agree that PaymentDAO is the right place for it since it returns Payments, however it's fine to pass the purchaseId if the rest of your DAO code is consistent with that approach.

Comment: @Jason Was thinking along ORM lines where relationships are at an entity level

Comment: +1 * 2: ORM = *Object* relational mapper. Deal with objects. When you start thinking in primary keys, you're too close to the database to do things the right way.

Comment: @Ryan I was just suggesting keeping consistent with the rest of the OPs codebase.

Answer (score 0):

A Purchase'knows' about its payments - so ask it. aka 'don't call me I'll call you'

Personally I create a class hierarchy like

```
Purchases
Purchase 
PurchaseDAO

Payments 
Payment
PaymentDAO


Purchases purchases = Purchases.find(criteria); 
// user selects one of the purchases (say)
Purchase = purchase.load(purchaseId);
// calls 
PurchaseDAO.load(purchaseId);
// which calls
Payments payment = Purchase.findPayments(); 
// calls 
Payments.find(purchaseId);
// calls 
PaymentDAO.find(purchaseId);
```

At the end you'll have a Purchase object which you can interrogate about its payments.
If there are likely to be many payments against a purchase you can defer loading the payments until needed.

This seems like extra work (and is) but it allows a clean seperation of business and persistence logic and I find pays back the small investment of creating the extra classes.